# Crypto class with Chatter

Tags: apex, chatter, crypto

We are using Salesforce as the front end (UI) for our CSR's; external system will be the system of record (backend).

We are planning to build eMessaging system using the combination of Salesforce custom object + chatter on the custom object.

Process:

1. A new custom object record will be created in Salesforce by CSR in Salesforce
2. CSR can post a chatter Feed on the record, which makes a webservice call and send this post to the external system
3. User in the external system can initiate a message on the same record, then they will call the webservice in Salesforce
4. Message will be posted on the feed on the custom object record

The above process is completely acheivable using the feed item trigger, webservice & chatter api.

However the business wants the message exchanged over these two system on the custom object record to be encrypted ; which is nothing but the feed messages in Salesforce should be enrcypted.

I was exploring the option of using Crypto class and I am able to encrypt the data sent from external system and store the encrypted data in Salesforce.

Is there a way to show the decrypted data (feed item message) when someone opens that record in Salesforce.

Thumb rule: Data (feed message stored in Salesforce should be encrypted and whenever someone view that record in Salesforce, we should decrypt the data and display in page)

Comment: I'm sure sfdcfox knows better, but I'm pretty sure all traffic is encrypted in transit. Do you really need it to be encrypted at rest as well?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that out of the box.

Salesforce Shield (Platform Encryption) supports [encryption of Chatter Files](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_enable_files_attachments.htm&language=en_US&type=0) at rest, but not actual Chatter Feeds.

There are third party solutions such as [CipherCloud](https://www.ciphercloud.com/blog/ciphercloud-salesforce-chatter-encrypts-sensitive-information-helps-compliance/) that will encrypt Chatter Feeds at rest.